# How to get all parents of <li> tag onclick of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing dynatree so nodes are place in ul and li tags. the problem I am getting is I am not getting parents of clicked li element.

Here is my html code,

```
<ul class="bulk">

 <li>gp1
   <ul>
    <li>gp2
    <ul>
        <li>gp3
            <ul>
                <li>c1
                <li>c2
                <li>c3
            </ul>
        <li>gp4
    </ul>
  </ul>
 <li>gp5
   <ul>
    <li>gp6
    <ul>
        <li>gp7
            <ul>
                <li>c4
                <ul>
                <li>c5
                <li>c6
                </ul>

            </ul>
        <li>gp8
        <li>gp9
    </ul>
    <li>gp10
</ul>
</ul>
```

Here is my jquery method

```
   $('ul.bulk li').click(function(e) 
                { 
                 //alert($(this).find("span.t").text());
                 alert(e.html());
                });
```

Here is my fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/ojnLrcjz/

The problem I am getting is if click on `gp3` it alerts me 3 times, but I want if I click on `gp3` it should alert its parents(gp1 and gp2). Here I place all li and ul dynamically except  tag. How to achive this please help me in this

Comment: You don't close any of the `<li>` elements. Is this intentional, an oversight,  or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.bulk li').click(function (e) {
        if($(e.target).is(this)){
            $(this).parentsUntil('.bulk', 'li').each(function(){
                alert(this.firstChild.nodeValue)
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2Lgamha2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helped me. but now I got actual problem, I m implemnting dynatree using http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-api.html. So the above solution is not working with Dynatree.

Comment: You will get detailed documentation here http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html